# Symfony2/Doctrine2.4 "It's a requirement to specify a Metadata Driver"

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to use some of the features of Doctrine 2.4 (mainly named entity listeners) and $event->properyHasChanged('property') and updated my composer.json to this collection:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sprain/validator-bundle": "dev-master",
        "willdurand/geocoder-bundle": "@stable",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "escapestudios/wsse-authentication-bundle": "2.3.x-dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "luxifer/doctrine-functions": "dev-master"

    },
```

The composer.phar updates without problems until the end.
After updating or when I try to use any console method (or the symfony2 app) I'm getting this error:

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                                                                                          
  It's a requirement to specify a Metadata Driver and pass it to Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::setMetadataDriverImpl().
```

My Doctrine configuration is as follows:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
```

Rolling back to doctrine 2.2 works.
Is there a good example of symfony2 and Doctrine 2.4? Because even in the current version (2.6  of Symfony2 they are using an older version of Doctrine.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration as stated in the [Doctrine Bundle docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration.rst) is as follows:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_mapping: true
    # the standard distribution overrides this to be true in debug, false otherwise
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
    proxy_namespace: Proxies
    proxy_dir: %kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies
    default_entity_manager: default
    metadata_cache_driver: array
    query_cache_driver: array
    result_cache_driver: array
```

As you can see it adds a Metadata Driver of type array.

Try and see if this solves your problem.